# When is docker-compose.yaml re-parsed?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**Scenario**:

With the following `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: 3

services:

 helloworld:
    image: hello-world
    container_name: hello-world

  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami
    container_name: whoami
```

- containers are started with `docker-compose up`
- `docker-compose.yaml` is then edited to expose a port

```
version: 3

services:

 helloworld:
    image: hello-world
    container_name: hello-world

  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami
    container_name: whoami
    ports:
      - 10000:80
```

- `whoami` is restarted via `docker-compose restart whoami`

**Problem**: the port is not exposed.

**My question**: what is the correct command to restart a container (previouly started as part of a `docker-compose up`) so that its (modified) definition in `docker-compose.yaml` is taken into account?

**Note**: restarting everything with `docker-compose down && docker-compose up` correctly exposes the port. What I want to avoid is to interfere with other running containers when modifying a single one.

Comment: Stop and remove the old container then up a new container with the updated config.

Comment: did you try building just the changed service so no other service will be interfered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only another `docker-compose up` seems to work.
According to docker-compose up documentation:

> If there are existing containers for a service, and the service’s configuration or image was changed after the container’s creation, docker-compose up picks up the changes by stopping and recreating the containers (preserving mounted volumes).

Comment: why? could you please provide a short explanation about your answer?